# Can no longer upload images on Magento 1.9 now Flash is no longer supported

Tags: magento-1.9, image

Is there any way to still upload images on Magento 1.9 now that flash is not supported on Chrome or any other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like Filezilla to connect to your server, and add the images by simply uploading them

Answer (score 0):

Flash uploader was removed to being insecure and replaced with javascript uploader. Please apply the correct patch 8788 or update the store to 1.9.4.5 / OpenMage Project to avoid further disruption.